# Query to get payroll element details with tis rules and rule values in oracle Fusion?

Tags: element, migrate

I want to Migrate payroll elments from one instance to another using HDl.
But not be able to get all elemtnts rules details.

i have uploaded using .dat file.its successfully done.
but not all elements.
problem is,i am not be able to get all elements with its rules.